# class junit.framework.TestSuite cannot be cast to class org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit, junit5

I am new to JAVA and Junit and trying to do something simple. I have the test passed but I see in the terminal initailizationError side this error "class junit.framework.TestSuite cannot be cast to class org.junit.jupiter.api.Test"  This is the version of my Junit dependencies.

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.9.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.9.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <version>RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
```

This is the test that I am trying to run

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;

/**
 * Unit test for simple App.
 */
public class AppTest
    extends TestCase
{
    @Test
    public void firstTest() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(2, 2);

    }

    /**
     * Create the test case
     *
     * @param testName name of the test case
     */


    /**
     * @return the suite of tests being tested
     */
    public static Test suite()
    {
        return (Test) new TestSuite( AppTest.class );
    }

    /**
     * Rigourous Test :-)
     */
    public void testApp()
    {
        assertTrue( true );
    }
}
```

I could not understand the error as it is my first time useing it

Comment: Using `extends TestCase` is JUnit 3..that will not work..furthermore `<version>RELEASE</version>` this will not work... also you have a dependency to `<artifactId>junit</artifactId>` which is JUnit 4... you have to decide to use either JUnit 3, JUnit 4 or JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5)... ? And apart from that you are mixing `import junit.framework.TestSuite;` .I strongly recommend to read the docs https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest fix is for you to delete your `suite` method. You don't need it, and your tests will run quite happily without it. Once you are a bit more confident and familiar with Java and JUnit, then *maybe* suites will help you organise and group tests, but you can certainly start without them.

The way you are attempting to create a test suite seems to follow the approach of JUnit 3, but you are using JUnit 5. JUnit changed a lot from JUnit 3 and JUnit 4, and also from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5, so it's not surprising that something from JUnit 3 doesn't work with JUnit 5.

I hadn't seen this way of writing test suites before, but I did find that [this page](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/junit-api-additional-classes/) talks about JUnit 5 and then presents examples using JUnit 3. To be quite frank I found the content of that page to be of poor quality and cannot recommend it. If you are using that page to learn about JUnit then I would advise you to look elsewhere.

Comment: This worked! thank you. No, I am not learning from this page I just started and I am trying to figure it out by myself! If you have any recommended pages where I can learn that will be amazing! Thank you in advance

Comment: @MohamadAlzaim: glad to have helped. Sorry, Stack Overflow isn't a place to ask for recommendations of tutorial sites, so I can't suggest one. However, taking another look at your class, I noted another couple of things which are conventions from JUnit 3 which are no longer needed in JUnit 5 but are not causing any harm. Firstly, you don't need `extends TestCase` any more, and secondly, test method names no longer need to begin with ` test`. All you need for a test method to be picked up as a JUnit 5 test is the `@Test` annotation on the method.

Answer (score 0):

the issue comes from these lines :

```
    public static Test suite()
    {
        return (Test) new TestSuite( AppTest.class );
    }
```

you are trying to cast 2 different Classes :

```
class junit.framework.TestSuite
```

to

```
class org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
```

which are 2 different classes , you can simply remove this function and the error will be fixed.

or if you want to have a **TestSuite** to bundle a few unit test cases and run them together,it can be in a separate class.

like what described in this [article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_suite_test.htm)

hope this helps !!!